# PostgreSQL audit table design with Multiple "User types"

Tags: postgresql, database-design, audit-logging

I'm trying to implement an Audit table design in PostgreSQL, where I have different types of user id's that can be audited.

Let's say I have a table named **admins** (which belong to an organization), and table **superadmins** (which don't).

```
CREATE TABLE example.organizations (
  id SERIAL UNIQUE,
  company_name varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  phone varchar(20) NOT NULL check (phone ~ '^[0-9]+$')
);
```

and an example of a potential admin design

```
CREATE TABLE example.admins (
  id serial primary_key,
  admin_type varchar not null,
  #... shared data
  check constraint admin_type in ("super_admins", "regular_admins")
);

CREATE TABLE example.regular_admins (
  id integer primary key,
  admin_type varchar not null default "regular_admins"
  organization_id integer references example.organizations(id),
  #... other regular admin fields
  foreign key (id, admin_type) references example.admins (id, admin_type),
  check constraint admin_type = "regular_admins"
);

CREATE TABLE example.super_admins (
  id integer primary key,
  admin_type varchar not null default "super_admins"
  #... other super admin fields
  foreign key (id, admin_type) references example.admins (id, admin_type),
  check constraint admin_type = "super_admins"
);
```

Now an audit table

```
CREATE TABLE audit.organizations (
  audit_timestamp timestamp not null default now(),
  operation text,
  admin_id integer primary key,
  before jsonb,
  after jsonb,
);
```

This calls for inheritance or polymorphism at some level, but I'm curious about how to design it.  I've heard that using PostgreSQL's inheritance functionality is not always a great way to go, although I'm finding it to fit this use case.

I'll need to be able to reference a single admin id in the trigger that updates the audit table, and it would be nice to be able to get the admin information when selecting from the audit table without using multiple queries.

Would it be better to use PostgreSQL inheritance or are there other ideas I haven't considered?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that it calls for inheritance or polymorphism. Admins and superadmins are both types of user, whose only difference is that the former belong to an organization. You can represent this with a single table and a nullable foreign key. No need to overcomplicate matters. Especially if you're using a `serial` as your primary key type: bad things happen if you confuse admin #2 for superadmin #2.

Comment: Perhaps the example is incomplete, but belonging to an organization is not the only difference, just a big one.  Also, I'm in the camp that a nullable foreign key is a bad idea in this example. (difference between a value not being known and not having a value.)  I'll update the example with an example parent admin table and cascade the changes in the example super_admins and regular_admins id columns (which is in part what I'm asking about).